# Flex Conditional Compile Error

Tags: actionscript-3, mxmlc

I'm doing the following:

```
CONFIG::TEST{
    rootURL = "myTestURL";
}

CONFIG::PROD{
    rootURL = "myProdURL";
}
```

In compiler arguments I have this:

```
-locale en_US -define+=CONFIG::AIR,true -define+=CONFIG::WEB,false 
-show-unused-type-selector-warnings=false 
-define+=CONFIG::PROD,false  -define+=CONFIG::TEST,true
```

But I'm getting errors for them both:

```
 Access of undefined property PROD.
 Access of undefined property TEST.
```

What is extremely odd is that this code works on my windows machine, but not on my mac. I've tried various things -- doing a clean checkout of code, cleaning the project, reinstalling Flash Builder. I also tried changing the order of the arguments, placing the last two in front of the selector warnings. That didn't help either.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Do you have linebreaks in there (when you entered them in the project properties)? Maybe that is messing up going from win -> mac, though I've never seen it happen. You can inspect your `.actionScriptProperties` file to see what it contains and/or replace the linebreaks w/spaces.

Comment: No, I added linebreaks just for formatting here. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You have unclosed braces in your post -- is that just a typo?

Comment: That was a typo that was fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set first `-define=CONFIG::AIR,true` without `+=` or use `-load-config+=configs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<flex-config>
  <compiler>
    <define append="true">
      <name>CONFIG::AIR</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </define>
     ...
  </compiler>
</flex-config>
```